# Parallel PowerMod

Tags: parallelization, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there anyway to parallelize the `PowerMod` function?

Here is my Left-To-Right modular exponentation:

```
AfshinPowerMod[a_, b_, m_] := (Output = 1; 
  Do[If[n == 1, Output = Mod[Output*Output*a, m], 
    Output = PowerMod[Output, 2, m]], {n, IntegerDigits[b, 2]}]; 
  Return[Output])
```

It computes roughly in the same time as original `PowerMod` for 10K digits numbers.

**Update**

*(Since for prime testing, 2 is the lowest base, I've used it for faster computation)*

Timing Result (Mathematica 8):

```
In[1]:= Total[DigitCount[2^100000 + 1]]

Out[1]= 30103


In[2]:= AbsoluteTiming[AfshinPowerMod[2, 2^100000 + 1, 2^100000 + 1]]

Out[2]= {91.839778,}


In[3]:= AbsoluteTiming[PowerMod[2, 2^100000 + 1, 2^100000 + 1]]

Out[3]= {92.9851312,}
```

As per J.M. request for **RandomPrime** (Based on the generated random prime timing differs, but yet it is roughly as fast as `PowerMod`)

```
In[41]:= prime = RandomPrime[10^2000]


In[43]:= AbsoluteTiming[PowerMod[2, prime, prime]]

Out[43]= {0.1406312, 2}

In[42]:= AbsoluteTiming[AfshinPowerMod[2, prime, prime]]

Out[42]= {0.1562399, 2}
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Why is the built-in version unsuitable?

Comment: Time. It take hours to compute PowerMod for 100K numbers while my cores are idle. I know I can distribute multiple numbers to multiple cores but I want to split PowerMod for a single number to decrease computing time.

Comment: FWIW, you could use `Fold[]` instead of `Do[]` in your implementation: `pmod[a_, b_, m_] := Fold[Mod[a^#2 #1^2, m] &, 1, IntegerDigits[b, 2]]`, though I'm not sure if this approach is still any better than the built-in one...

Comment: Reverse effect, added 0.5 second time to computation

Comment: If it's a matter of speed when you have 100K numbers, why do you need to split each number into cores? Wouldn't be equally efficient to just distribute the 100K numbers among the kernels?

Comment: Just use `ParallelMap` or `ParallelTabl`e to run `PowerMod` on your 100k numbers over all your cores.

Comment: I can distribute numbers among kernels but there some cases where I need to compute a single number as fast as possible. Because of nature of exponentiation which requires previous levels, I couldn't parallelize it so I asked others

Comment: I cannot reproduce @Mohsen's statement that AfshinPowerMod "computes roughly in the same time as original PowerMod for 10K digits numbers."  My timings have the built-in PowerMod orders of magnitude faster for input integers $a$ and $b$ tested with up to 25 thousand digits...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you have there is representative. Try, say, the output of `RandomPrime[]` as the modulus and base...

Comment: Why is the base always $2$?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the two timing tests given recently above, those with moduli $2^{100000}+1$ and `RandomPrime[10^1000]`. PowerMod remains faster than AfshinPowerMod. Finding the random primes takes almost all the CPU time, so I calculated them first then wrapped `AbsoluteTiming` around the two mod functions.

Comment: @KennyColnago I've update question. Consider.The question point is not the speed of this implementation but parallelizing that. Thanks