# Montgomery Modular Exponentiation

Tags: performance-tuning, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to write a Montgomery exponentiation based on [this](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/koren/arith/simulator/Montg/mm_sim_lesson_page2.html) which can compete with Mathematica `PowerMod`. [We](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/parallel-powermod) know that `PowerMod` uses square and multiply technique.
The speedup must be obtained by replacing modular operation mod n with modular operation mod 2^x. Can we accomplish this in Mathematica such that it take over from `PowerMod`? 
This is my implementation:

Global variables:

```
RLength = 0; R = 0; RM1=0; RInverse = 0; NPrime = 0; verbose = False;
```

and the MontExp (b^e mod n):

```
MontExp[b_, e_, n_] := (RLength = BitLength[n]; R = 2^RLength; RM1=R-1; 
  RInverse = PowerMod[R, -1, n]; NPrime = PowerMod[-n, -1, R]; 
  M = Mod[b*R, n]; Result = Mod[R, n]; 
  If[verbose, 
   Print["MontParams: R=", R, ", RInverse=", RInverse, " ,NPrime=", 
    NPrime, " ,M=", M]];
  Do[Result = Mont[Result, Result, n]; 
   If[expBit == 1, Result = Mont[Result, M, n]], {expBit, 
    IntegerDigits[e, 2]}]; Result = Mont[Result, 1, n]; Return[Result])
```

Mont function version 0:

```
Mont[u_, v_, n_] := (z = Mod[u*v*RInverse, n]; 
  If[verbose, Print["Monto ", u, " * ", v, " => ", z]]; Return[z]);
```

Mont function version 1:

```
Mont[u_, v_, n_] := (t = u*v; 
   z = BitShiftRight[(t + Mod[t*NPrime, R] n), RLength]; 
   If[verbose, Print["Monto ", u, " * ", v, " => ", z]]; Return[z]);
```

Mont function version 2:

```
Mont[u_, v_, n_] := (t = u*v; 
   z = BitShiftRight[(t + BitAnd[t*NPrime, RM1] n), RLength]; 
   If[verbose, Print["Monto ", u, " * ", v, " => ", z]]; Return[z]);
```

and Timings:

```
p = 2^20000 + 1;
```

Mathematica PowerMod:

```
Timing[PowerMod[2, p, p] == 2]
```

> {1.529, False}

Mont v0

> {3.432, False}

Mont v1

> {7.332, False}

Mont v2

> {3.541, False}

As you can see as I tried to improve it with binary shifts instead of modular operations, it had negative impact on the speed. That's probably because of non-native implementation in Mathematica. Any idea to improve it?

--

**Update**

I've learnt that `Mod[b, 2^n] == BitAnd[b, 2^n-1]` so I changed the Version 2 to use `BitAnd`, but yet no gain in compare to original `PowerMod`...

**Update 2**

It seems that because of its reliance on shifts, the speedups are only for 2^k+1 numbers. However I saw an amazing result from @Simoon-Woods answer:

```
list = (2^# + 1) & /@ Range[5000, 100000, 5000];

PowerModTimings = First[Timing[PowerMod[2, #, #]]] & /@ list
    {0.047,0.265,0.717,1.529,2.871,4.336,6.506,9.173,11.934,16.879,20.623,25.772,30.373,37.3,45.49,55.131,63.274,73.788,85.114,96.112}

MontExpTimingsV2 = First[Timing[MontExp[2, #, #]]] & /@ list (*Mont version 2*)
    {0.063,0.156,0.312,0.483,5.258,0.92,4.711,1.56,8.081,18.642,2.949,3.51,16.13,18.268,36.91,5.569,15.413,28.236,106.143,60.388}

MontExpTimingsV0 = First[Timing[MontExp[2, #, #]]] & /@ list (*Mont version 0*)
{0.047,0.093,0.188,0.234,2.418,0.53,2.246,0.858,3.417,8.58,1.451,1.669,7.051,8.003,18.221,2.824,6.91,13.245,51.231,29.047}
```

And plotting the result:

```
ListLinePlot[{PowerModTimings, MontExpTimingsV2, MontExpTimingsV0}]
```

[image]

**Update 3**

I've added timings for `Mont` version 0 based on @Simon-Woods answer. Great timings ...

Comment: Look into `Compile` with `CompilationTarget-> "C"`.

Comment: You have to be careful though because `Compile` expects machine-sized integers in most places. You'd need to use an alternate representation.

Comment: I tied it and because of the "machine-size" integers it's useless for this scenario.

Comment: You could probably do some trick like representing it as a list of integers to get it to compile, but I don't know if that overhead would be more or less than the benefit you would get from compiling.

Comment: I think your questions are good ones, but unfortunately your usual goal of speeding up number-theoretical functions by rewriting them at the top level is in general going to be somewhere between extremely difficult and impossible. Might I suggest that you instead consider doing this with GMP in a MathLink program?

Comment: @OleksandrR., thanks for the suggestion, I tried it now, but Mathlink is roughly 5 times slower than Mathematica itself with the same input, so going further and doing bit manipulation would make it even slower

Comment: Can you give some details of your approach? MathLink should not be that horribly slow, while GMP aims to be the fastest multiprecision library available. Given that *Mathematica* uses MathLink and GMP anyway, I would expect at least comparable speed, and the possibility of improving on what already exists if your proposed algorithm is really better. Are you finding that transfers between *Mathematica* and your own program are the bottleneck, or something else?

Comment: I've measured the time only for computing the result using MathLink .NET API, and about GMP I've used this wrapper (http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/) which its performance is obviously slower than native Mathematica code. Also I wondered when my simple manual Left-To-Right PowerMod implmentation became faster than GMP PowerMod (of course the wrapping may have an effect on this)

Comment: Probably best to try with the C version. http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the example problem I get about a factor of 4 speedup over `PowerMod` by memoizing `Mont`. This of course means that `Mont` should not contain any global variables so I rewrote the code slightly:

```
MontExp[b_, e_, n_] := Module[
  {RLength, R, RM1, RInverse, NPrime, M, Result},
  RLength = BitLength[n]; R = 2^RLength; RM1 = R - 1;
  RInverse = PowerMod[R, -1, n]; NPrime = PowerMod[-n, -1, R];
  M = Mod[b R, n]; Result = Mod[R, n];
  Do[
   Result = Mont[Result, Result, n, NPrime, RM1, RLength];
   If[expBit == 1, Result = Mont[Result, M, n, NPrime, RM1, RLength]]
   , {expBit, IntegerDigits[e, 2]}];
  Mont[Result, 1, n, NPrime, RM1, RLength]];

mem : Mont[u_, v_, n_, NPrime_, RM1_, RLength_] :=
 mem = Module[{t = u v}, BitShiftRight[(t + BitAnd[t*NPrime, RM1] n), RLength]]
```

Testing:

```
p = 2^20000 + 1;

Timing[res1 = PowerMod[2, p, p];]
(* {3.546, Null} *)

Timing[res2 = MontExp[2, p, p];]
(* {0.765, Null} *)

res1 == res2
(* True *)
```

Comment: You might consider using the memoization notation I proposed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121).  I think with exposure it will be easy to read and also more concise and less error-prone. (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good idea, thanks. It makes for much easier reading when the pattern is long.

Comment: @SimonWoods, thanks for memoizing trick, take a look at my updates

Comment: @MohsenAfshin, I should read the question more carefully - I didn't notice that `Mont` version 0 was the faster one. Interesting how jagged the timings are for `MontExp` compared to `PowerMod`.